# Insert data from list into excel worksheet using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

for example lets say I have two different list

```
list1 = [apple, orange, banana]
list2 = [red, blue, green]
```

and I wanted to insert both these list into the same excel sheet but under different columns. How would I do this using pandas dataframe. example below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAIAa.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'list1':list1,'list2':list2}).to_excel('my_excel.xlsx')`

Comment: And if you put that dict into a list [ ]?